# Java twenty one card

Tags: java

I have an assignment that I am having trouble with. The point is to have the program print out cards with blackjack values. It does not need to actually add the cards together, but just display the name of the card and value.

My trouble comes in with displaying the number after ace,king,queen, and jack. my code is

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class Card
{
public static final String FACES[] = {"ZERO","ACE","TWO","THREE","FOUR",
        "FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","JACK","QUEEN","KING"};

//instance variables
private String suit;
private int face;

//constructors
public Card( String s, int f)
{
    suit = s;
    face = f;
}

// modifiers
public void setFace( int f)
{
    face = f;
}

public void setSuit( String s)
{
    suit = s;
}

//accessors
public String getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

public int getFace()
{
    return face;
}

//toString
public String toString()
{
    return FACES[face] + " of " + suit;
}
 }
```

---

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CardRunner
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Card one = new Card("SPADES", 9);
    out.println(one.getSuit());
    out.println(one.getFace());

    Card two = new Card("DIAMONDS", 1);
    out.println(two);
    two.setFace(3);
    out.println(two);

    Card three = new Card("CLUBS", 4);
    out.println(three);

    Card four = new Card("SPADES", 1);
    out.println(four);

    Card five = new Card("HEARTS", 13);
    out.println(five);

    Card six = new Card("HEARTS", 11);
    out.println(six);

    Card seven = new Card("CLUBS", 12);
    out.println(seven);     
}
}
```

I was thinking that I would add a method that would call to super(s,f) as that is what we are learning and the point of the assignment is to use the call to super. I am just having trouble making it display the numbers.

my output is:

```
SPADES
9
ACE of DIAMONDS
THREE of DIAMONDS
FOUR of CLUBS
ACE of SPADES
KING of HEARTS
JACK of HEARTS
QUEEN of CLUBS
```

The output I need is:

```
SPADES 
9 
ACE of DIAMONDS 
THREE of DIAMONDS 
FOUR of CLUBS 
ACE of SPADES 11 
KING of HEARTS 10 
JACK of HEARTS 10
QUEEN of CLUBS 10
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, what card would `ZERO` represent?

Comment: What would prevent `ACE of DIAMONDS` and the other cards from also printing out the value?

Comment: I had the same question, but didn't argue with my teacher. I wasn't sure why we didn't need the value, but my teacher sent us what she wanted the output to be and it was the one I put up

Answer (score 1):

Just store another variable for the actual value of the Card.

Note: I would implement `getValue()` instead of `getFace()` to return the "proper" value of the card and not the index of the array.

```
//instance variables
private String suit;
private int face;
private int value;

//constructors
public Card( String s, int f)
{
    suit = s;
    face = f;
    value = f;              // This handles 2..10
    if (f > 10) value = 10; // Face values are all 10
    if (f == 1) value = 11; // Ace. Remove if 1 and 11 should be different
}

public String toString()
{
    String s = FACES[face] + " of " + suit;
    if (face > 10 || face == 1) {
        s += " " + value;
    }
    return s;
}
```